# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.design:21.0.3

Tags: android

I added the following line to my `build.gradle(Module:app)`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'
```

But when executing **Gradle** I'm getting

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.design:21.0.3

I got that code from the android support design library and added it to a new project. I added it to the dependency section as such:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.solodroid.androidnewsapp'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
    compile files('libs/StartAppInAppPlus-2.3.jar')


}
```

Comment: Have you added the google() repository in build.gradle?

Comment: Your complie sdk version is 26, use support lib version same 26.

Comment: yes i have @Raz

Comment: You need to manually install the support library below version 26 from Tools -> SDK Manager. But you're better using support library 26 as your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` both is version 26.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same version of appcompat as your sdk version. Also in newer android studio use implementation keyword.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

**IMP**

Or first check your sdk that you have downloaded the version 21.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

You should add official google repository in app gradle. Also on project gradle if other modules need that repository.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}

...

android {
...
```